# Lifecam Cinema prevents boot into Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: boot, webcam

When I have the [lifecam cinema webcam](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/p/lifecam-cinema/H5D-00013)  plugged in, then there are problems booting into the operating system (ubuntu 13.1). Since I'm new to Ubuntu, I can only describe what happens. It boots as far as a maroon screen (unlike the themed screen in the current desktop) asking for a password. I type, but it doesn't show up on the password input field. Then I notice the light on the webcam, then a tabla sound, then freeze.

After I unplug the webcam, Ubuntu boots normally, to the themed password entry screen.

Anyone able to provide guidance to fix this, or is it that Ubuntu can't use this device?

Later, Thanks for the directions. I booted, then put in the webcam, noticed that it lights up and then goes off, the system continues to run, so I ran "dmesg | tail -n 25" and got these lines related to the webcam:

```
[   39.563813] usbcore: registered new interface driver usblp
[  235.380107] usb 2-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[  235.489287] usb 2-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=075d
[  235.489292] usb 2-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  235.489296] usb 2-1.3: Product: Microsoft\xffffffc2\xffffffae\xffffffae LifeCam Cinema(TM)
[  235.489299] usb 2-1.3: Manufacturer: Microsoft
[  235.504605] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[  240.624227] 5:3:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x82
[  240.633185] usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio
[  240.636551] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Microsoft\xffffffc2\xffffffae\xffffffae LifeCam Cinema(TM) (045e:075d)
[  240.643626] input: Microsoft\xffffffc2\xffffffae\xffffffae LifeCam Cinema(TM) as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/input/input12
[  240.643705] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[  240.643707] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[  245.776178] 5:3:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x82
[  250.776304] 5:3:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x82
[  255.904243] 5:3:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x82
[  260.904238] 5:3:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x82
```

for the second command (sudo lsusb -v) I got

```
          Self Powered
    MaxPower                2mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    204 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         7 Printer
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Printer
      bInterfaceProtocol      2 Bidirectional
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x08  EP 8 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x89  EP 9 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        2
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol    255 Vendor Specific Protocol
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x06  EP 6 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x87  EP 7 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        2
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    212 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x06  EP 6 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x87  EP 7 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
  bLength                10
  bDescriptorType         6
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  bNumConfigurations      1
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1737:0071 Linksys WUSB600N v1 Dual-Band Wireless-N Network Adapter [Ralink RT2870]
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x1737 Linksys
  idProduct          0x0071 WUSB600N v1 Dual-Band Wireless-N Network Adapter [Ralink RT2870]
  bcdDevice            1.01
  iManufacturer           1 Cisco-Linksys LLC
  iProduct                2 Dual-Band Wireless-N USB Network Adapter
  iSerial                 3 (error)
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           67
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              450mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           7
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol    255 Vendor Specific Protocol
      iInterface              5 (error)
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x04  EP 4 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x05  EP 5 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x06  EP 6 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
  bLength                10
  bDescriptorType         6
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  bNumConfigurations      1
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass         0 Unused
  bDeviceProtocol         0 Full speed (or root) hub
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x1d6b Linux Foundation
  idProduct          0x0002 2.0 root hub
  bcdDevice            3.11
  iManufacturer           3 Linux 3.11.0-13-generic ehci_hcd
  iProduct                2 EHCI Host Controller
  iSerial                 1 0000:00:1a.7
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           25
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower                0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         9 Hub
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 Unused
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 Full speed (or root) hub
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0004  1x 4 bytes
        bInterval              12
Hub Descriptor:
  bLength               9
  bDescriptorType      41
  nNbrPorts             6
  wHubCharacteristic 0x000a
    No power switching (usb 1.0)
    Per-port overcurrent protection
  bPwrOn2PwrGood       10 * 2 milli seconds
  bHubContrCurrent      0 milli Ampere
  DeviceRemovable    0x00
  PortPwrCtrlMask    0xff
 Hub Port Status:
   Port 1: 0000.0503 highspeed power enable connect
   Port 2: 0000.0100 power
   Port 3: 0000.0503 highspeed power enable connect
   Port 4: 0000.0100 power
   Port 5: 0000.0100 power
   Port 6: 0000.0100 power
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered

Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass         0 Unused
  bDeviceProtocol         0 Full speed (or root) hub
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x1d6b Linux Foundation
  idProduct          0x0001 1.1 root hub
  bcdDevice            3.11
  iManufacturer           3 Linux 3.11.0-13-generic uhci_hcd
  iProduct                2 UHCI Host Controller
  iSerial                 1 0000:00:1a.2
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           25
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower                0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         9 Hub
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 Unused
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 Full speed (or root) hub
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0002  1x 2 bytes
        bInterval             255
Hub Descriptor:
  bLength               9
  bDescriptorType      41
  nNbrPorts             2
  wHubCharacteristic 0x000a
    No power switching (usb 1.0)
    Per-port overcurrent protection
  bPwrOn2PwrGood        1 * 2 milli seconds
  bHubContrCurrent      0 milli Ampere
  DeviceRemovable    0x00
  PortPwrCtrlMask    0xff
 Hub Port Status:
   Port 1: 0000.0100 power
   Port 2: 0000.0100 power
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass         0 Unused
  bDeviceProtocol         0 Full speed (or root) hub
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x1d6b Linux Foundation
  idProduct          0x0001 1.1 root hub
  bcdDevice            3.11
  iManufacturer           3 Linux 3.11.0-13-generic uhci_hcd
  iProduct                2 UHCI Host Controller
  iSerial                 1 0000:00:1a.1
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           25
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower                0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         9 Hub
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 Unused
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 Full speed (or root) hub
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0002  1x 2 bytes
        bInterval             255
Hub Descriptor:
  bLength               9
  bDescriptorType      41
  nNbrPorts             2
  wHubCharacteristic 0x000a
    No power switching (usb 1.0)
    Per-port overcurrent protection
  bPwrOn2PwrGood        1 * 2 milli seconds
  bHubContrCurrent      0 milli Ampere
  DeviceRemovable    0x00
  PortPwrCtrlMask    0xff
 Hub Port Status:
   Port 1: 0000.0100 power
   Port 2: 0000.0100 power
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered

Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass         0 Unused
  bDeviceProtocol         0 Full speed (or root) hub
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x1d6b Linux Foundation
  idProduct          0x0001 1.1 root hub
  bcdDevice            3.11
  iManufacturer           3 Linux 3.11.0-13-generic uhci_hcd
  iProduct                2 UHCI Host Controller
  iSerial                 1 0000:00:1a.0
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           25
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower                0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         9 Hub
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 Unused
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 Full speed (or root) hub
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0002  1x 2 bytes
        bInterval             255
Hub Descriptor:
  bLength               9
  bDescriptorType      41
  nNbrPorts             2
  wHubCharacteristic 0x000a
    No power switching (usb 1.0)
    Per-port overcurrent protection
  bPwrOn2PwrGood        1 * 2 milli seconds
  bHubContrCurrent      0 milli Ampere
  DeviceRemovable    0x00
  PortPwrCtrlMask    0xff
 Hub Port Status:
   Port 1: 0000.0100 power
   Port 2: 0000.0100 power
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered
```

Also, I tried skype with the webcam, and it runs. So, it's just a question as to how I can get Ubuntu to boot with it.

Comment: Can't you boot *then* plug it in? Also, what model version of the camera are you using?

Comment: Boot the computer, then plug it and add the output of `dmesg | tail -n 25` to your question and then someone might be able to help. You can also add the output of `sudo lsusb -v`.

Comment: what model version **of the camera**, @seth, not **Ubuntu**. Got a link now anyway - Has this camera ever worked with Ubuntu or Linux of some description? - the link you gave had lots of things with 'Microsoft' and 'windows' on them. Your `lsusb -v` output is not complete by the way - it has something about a `printer`?

Comment: @wilf Oops. I could have sworn you said Ubuntu... My bad, sorry.

Comment: There is no model or version printed on the webcam, that's why I gave the manufacturer's link to the item. Yes I edited the dmesg output, and there is a line referring to the printer, but we're only interested in the webcam, so I edited it out. Do you need that part too? The camera does work in Ubuntu, I was able to run it in Skype, but only after inserting it post boot. The problem is that if the camera is in during boot, it prevents me from logging in, since it seems to query the camera and then freeze.

Comment: Still can't see anything on a camera - plug the camera in *then* run `lsusb -v` - find something related to your camera *(on mine: `Bus 002 Device 003: ID 5986:0292 Acer, Inc`)*, and add *the relevant piece below it* in.

Comment: Any information you can get from `lshw` will actually be more useful - it is in [Software Centre](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/lshw-gtk/), and can be used to find info on the hardware - [here is mine again on the camera](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uAUqI.png).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same camera, two of them actually.  They worked fine in 12.10 but don't work right in 13.04/13.10 and I want to say it was the kernel that changed but I'm not sure.  Mine does not completely lock up the PC but rather holds for 30 seconds or so with the blue LED on and then the light goes off and I can continue to log in.  It does basically lock up the login screen while the LED is on though.

It's also really flaky with video chat.  The camera opens on Google Hangouts for the preview but then has no sound and locks up completely within a few seconds of the other person connecting.  If I open the Sound Properties app on the Inputs page with the LifeCam microphone selected (which turns on the camera to show the live preview) and leave the Sound Properties page open while I open the Hangouts chat then the camera continues working perfectly.

When I plug in my camera (tested with two LifeCam Cinema units across multiple Ubuntu 13.10 machines) I get the following in dmesg:

```
[254029.860475] usb 2-4: new high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[254030.008797] usb 2-4: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=075d
[254030.008802] usb 2-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[254030.008805] usb 2-4: Product: Microsoft\xffffffc2\xffffffae\xffffffae LifeCam Cinema(TM)
[254030.008808] usb 2-4: Manufacturer: Microsoft
[254030.010071] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Microsoft\xffffffc2\xffffffae\xffffffae LifeCam Cinema(TM) (045e:075d)
[254030.015924] input: Microsoft\xffffffc2\xffffffae\xffffffae LifeCam Cinema(TM) as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-4/2-4:1.0/input/input65
[254035.137019] 6:3:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x82
[254040.661359] 6:3:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x82
[254045.661708] 6:3:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x82
[254050.858101] 6:3:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x82
[254055.858452] 6:3:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x82
```

I'm also getting things like:

```
[98773.902443] uvcvideo: Failed to set UVC probe control : -110 (exp. 26).
[98773.902445] 6:3:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x82
[98778.902790] uvcvideo: Failed to query (130) UVC probe control : -110 (exp. 26).
[98778.902797] 6:3:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x82
[98778.903125] uvcvideo: Failed to set UVC probe control : -32 (exp. 26).
```

Here's lsusb:

```
adam@Adam-Desktop:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 045e:075d Microsoft Corp. LifeCam Cinema
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04da:2497 Panasonic (Matsushita) HDC-TM700
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0e79:1411 Archos, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 045e:075d Microsoft Corp. LifeCam Cinema
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 027: ID 1532:0015 Razer USA, Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1b1c:1b09 Corsair 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 010 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
```

Try installing the 3.13 kernel.  That's what I'm using (3.13-rc2) from the Kernel PPA.  It might fix it to at least be able to boot through it if you wait.  I'm using Ubuntu GNOME 13.10 + 3.13-rc2 amd64 kernel + Oibaf graphics drivers PPA on an Intel i7 930 + Radeon 5870 system though the system itself doesn't seem to matter as I use my second camera on my AMD A8-3870K based system and it does the same thing.